# Yeoman sub generator: using answers to prompts from main generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have written a Yeoman sub generator and I want to access the answers acquired from the prompts in the main (parent) generator. The format to access the answers in the main generator's index.js file is `this.promptName`. Is it possible to retrieve those answers within the sub generator?

This is what I currently have but (obviously) doesn't work:

```
var ComponentGenerator = yeoman.generators.NamedBase.extend({

    init: function () {
        if (this.wordpress) { // this.wordpress set from main generator
            console.log('is wp');
        } else {
            console.log('not wp');
        }
    }
});
module.exports = ComponentGenerator;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass them as options to the sub generator:

```
this.composeWith('subgenerator', {options: {name: 'some-name'}});
```

Then in your sub generator:

```
this.option('name', {/* settings */});
```

See the full documentation here:

- composeWith: http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html
- Options/Arguments: http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html